# How to save a specific array element in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am receiving a JSON object with an array property. I would like to search the array and save only the element that matches my criteria. My input looks like this:

```
{
  "identifier": [
    { "system" : "Source1", "value" : "TheValueIDontWant"},
    { "system" : "Source2", "value" : "TheValueIWant"}
  ]
}
```

and I would like my output to look like this:

```
{
  "SourceID": "TheValueIWant"
}
```

So in this case, I want to search the identifier array for the element which has Source2 as the system and save its corresponding value to my new property.

Is there a way to do this in Logstash?

Thanks

Comment: at worst you could use the ruby plugin

Answer (score 0):

Got this answer from someone on the elastic forum. Using ruby was indeed the answer and this is how:

```
ruby {
code => '
    ids = event.get("identifier")
    if ids.is_a? Array
        ids.each { |x|
            if x["system"] == "Source2"
                event.set("SourceID", x["value"])
            end
        }
    end
'
```

}